# Why height of paragraph and text box is not same in a Div?

Tags: html, css

I have created a div with two child elements.

- a paragraph
- a input with type text.

I have provided same height to both of them but on browser I am not getting same height for them.

my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./StyleSheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="textWbutton">
        <p>Enter Name</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="I am placeholder" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

MY CSS

```
html,body
{
    font-size: 0px;
}

.textWbutton
{
}

.textWbutton input[type='text']
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;

    height: 30px;
    display: inline;

    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    border: 1px solid Black;
}

.textWbutton p
{
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;

    height: 100%;
    display: inline; 
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    border: 1px solid Black;    
}
```

Here if the fiddle for the same. http://jsfiddle.net/apoorvasahay01/mByYC/1/

Please let me know what could have gone wrong here.

Comment: Please use `<label>` for accessibility and usability.

Comment: @eyelidlessness I have replaced p with label but I am getting the same thing on browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of inline.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mByYC/6/)

Or use `display: table-cell` and add `display: table-row` to .textWbutton

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mByYC/8/)

Answer (score 5):

That is because you have not made a reset of their custom attributes. Like `<p>` and `<input>` by default have some padding and margin and when you add a height, it populates accordingly.

Comment: Cant expect a better answer than this :)

Comment: So add something like `padding: 0; margin: 0` before setting their left and right padding.

Comment: Yes - @MichaelPeterson Ideally, as a css reset has to be declared for consistency like [Eric mayer CSS Reset Tools](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: Yep @NathanLee, agreed. I use something similar myself.

Comment: @Apoorvasahay - From you snippet, there can be solutions like `display:inline-block;` or `display:table-cell;`. But if you look at a long term perspective for your solution, I suggest you to use a CSS Reset as I mentioned just above this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use padding to fit it same as input.

```
.textWbutton p {
font-size: 15px;
margin: 0px;
height: 30px;
display: inline;
border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you display a block element like p as inline it gets the height from the line-height attribute which you haven't set. To get what you intent you should rather display it as inline-block or set the line-height.
http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/ has a nice explanation.